# How to manipulate toISOString output to look like the output from moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
  console.log(moment(foo).format());
```

gives me the output:     `2021-10-11T00:00:00+02:00`

```
  console.log(new Date(foo).toISOString());
```

gives me the output: `2021-10-10T22:00:00.000Z`

What do I need to do in order to get output #2 to match output #1 that uses moment?

Comment: The first output has a _timezone_, the latter is in UTC (as `toISOString` [always is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)). They're the same point in time.

Comment: moment also has `toISOString`. See [As ISO 8601 String](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)